# MySQL, grouping by and performing a SUM within the groups

Tags: mysql, sql

The table below contains records of shifts which have taken place.  The start and end fields are the start and end timestamps of those shifts.  I'm looking to build a query that will extract the total hours per month that the shifts cover.

Example table:

```
ID Start                End
1  2018-10-23 10:30:00  2018-10-23 11:45:00
2  2018-10-22 22:00:00  2018-10-22 23:00:00
3  2018-11-22 22:00:00  2018-11-22 23:00:00
```

The ideal output would read:

```
Month Hours
10    2:15
11    1:00
```

I've got some of the elements worked out, using a SUM(timediff(end,start)) and GROUP BY, but havn't managed to get something good out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select
  month(start) as month,
  time_format(sec_to_time(
    sum(timestampdiff(second, start, end))
  ), '%H:%i') as hours,
  sum(timestampdiff(second, start, end)) as seconds
from shift
group by month(start)
```

Result:

```
month  hours  seconds
-----  -----  -------
10     02:15  8,100
11     01:00  3,600
```

Note: I added the extra column `seconds` in case you want to use this numeric value to do some extra processing.